# Android (AndEngine): Sprite with body attached going up and down

Tags: android, andengine, physics

I was trying to make the enemies in my game go up and down; since I'm using a physic body with a Sprite on it I can't use entity modifiers, so I decided give the body a little push using the .setLinearVelocity(float x, float y) method every time its sprite reach a certain point in the screen.

With just one body works great, but I need to have other enemeis (same sprite, different body) spawning every 5 seconds and doing the same thing, but I don't know how to track them... I mean, I don't know how to control if each body reaches the Y location independently from one another...

For example, right now the code is like this:

```
private void add_Box_Face()
{
    float random_x = (float) (28 +  (int)(Math.random() * ((this.CAMERA_WIDTH - 28*2) + 1)));

    final Body rectangle_face_body;

    final Sprite rectangle_face = new Sprite(random_x, this.y, this.mRectangleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    rectangle_face_body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.m_PhysicsWorld, rectangle_face, BodyType.DynamicBody, this.BOX_FIXTURE_DEF);

    rectangle_face_body.setUserData("target");

            //I give the body a initial push
    rectangle_face_body.setLinearVelocity(0, -5);

            //I register an update handler to the sprite to control if it reaches a certain Y value
    rectangle_face.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
        {

               if (rectangle_face.getY() >= y-50)
               {
                       //Here I just use a flag so that later on below I can do the push
                 MyApp.this.setLinearVelocity = true;
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

    });

            //Here I register the physic connector and if the flag permits it, I push the body up
    this.m_PhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(rectangle_face, rectangle_face_body, true, false)
    {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
        {
            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if(MyApp.this.setLinearVelocity)
            {
                rectangle_face_body.setLinearVelocity(0, -3);
                MyApp.this.setLinearVelocity = false;
            }



        }
    });

    this.mscene.attachChild(rectangle_face);

}
```

With the code like this the first body do what is planned,  it moves up and down but as soon as another body pops up, it falls down and the other body goes up because the boolean setLinearVelocity is always set to true, so there is a costant push upwards; when a third body comes in, the second body falls down as well and this last one takes its place going up

With this code I didn't expect much else... but I don't know what else I can try... how can I control this?

Thanks in advance  :)

EDIT: Added working code in an anwser below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you separate the code for the enemy from the code for the update handler. Create a class Enemy that will contain the Sprite and Body, hold your Enemies in an array and override the onUpdate method of your PhysicsWorld so that it goes through the array of Enemies and does what you want to all of them.

Here's a code snippet showing a very simple way of doing this:

```
mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void reset() {}

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            for (Enemy e : enemies) {
                e.checkPositionAndBounce();
            }
        }
    });
```

Please note that this may not a very good idea as this code will probably run on a thread different to the one of the physics engine, which could cause all sorts of problems. A better way would be overriding the onUpdate method of PhysicsWorld:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
    super.onUpdate();
    for (Enemy e : enemies) {
        e.checkPositionAndBounce();
    }
}
```

If you are unsure of what the first snippet means, look up "anonymous inner class".

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for your help!

Yes I tried using an array and it works! I'm overriding the onUpdate method of PhyiscsWorld just like you said and it seems to be working pretty smoothly even with a dozen of moving objects (which is pretty much the worst case scenario for what I want to do).

I wanted to post what the code looks like now, in case someone who wants to do the same passes by, but since I don't have enough reputation I can't anweser my question just yet, and I don't want to add it to the original post cause it would become too long; Thanks again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the final working code (I didn't create a method to check the position or a class for the enemies just because right now I'm just messing around with the mechanics; I'll create a new project when I'm ready to really start):

```
this.m_PhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false)
{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
    {
        super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

        for(int i = 0; i <= MyApp.this.mSpriteCounter; i++)
        {

            if (rectangle_face[i].getY() >= y-50)
            {       
                final PhysicsConnector spritePhysicsConnector = m_PhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(rectangle_face[i]); 

                spritePhysicsConnector.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0, -3);      
             }
        }
    };
```

In this code rectangle_face[] is an array of Sprites; each sprite is created like this:

```
private void add_Box_Face()
{

    float random_x = (float) (28 +  (int)(Math.random() * ((this.CAMERA_WIDTH - 28*2) + 1)));

    final Body rectangle_face_body;


    rectangle_face[this.mSpriteCounter] = new Sprite(random_x, y, this.mRectangleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());


    rectangle_face_body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.m_PhysicsWorld, rectangle_face[this.mSpriteCounter], BodyType.DynamicBody, this.BOX_FIXTURE_DEF);

    rectangle_face_body.setUserData("target");

    rectangle_face_body.setLinearVelocity(0, -5);


    this.m_PhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(rectangle_face[this.mSpriteCounter], rectangle_face_body, true, false));

    this.mscene.attachChild(rectangle_face[this.mSpriteCounter]);

}
```

That's it, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for coming back and posting the code for others to use.